# How to: Check if current user is member of ‘domain admins’

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to verify that a provided username is a Domain Administrator in c#. 
Any idea's on how to do this?

Comment: Did you try _anything_ to solve your problem?

Comment: yes i mean asp .net c#

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WindowsIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the current user.

Then create a [WindowsPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the `WindowsIdentity`.

And check [WindowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Hope this can help you.

**EDIT** : I just see the ASP tag now... This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693043/httpcontext-current-user-httpcontext-user) could help you, same thing but for ASP.

Answer (score 0):

Function ADUserInfo(sLogonUser, cOption)

```
Dim oConnection
Dim oCommand
Dim oRoot
Dim oDomain
Dim sADsPath
Dim sDomain

sDomain = Mid(sLogonUser, 1, Instr(1, sLogonUser, "\") - 1)

Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
With oConnection
    .Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    .Mode = "1" 'Read
    .Properties("Encrypt Password") = True 
    .Open "Active Directory Provider"
End With

Set oCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
oCommand.ActiveConnection = oConnection

Set oRoot = GetObject("LDAP://" & sDomain & "/rootdse")
Set oDomain = GetObject("LDAP://" & sDomain & "/" & oRoot.Get("defaultNamingContext"))
sADsPath = "<" & oDomain.ADsPath & ">"


Select Case lcase(cOption) 

    Case "groups"

        ADUserInfo = ADUserGroups(sLogonUser, oConnection, oCommand, oRoot, oDomain, sADsPath)

    Case "name"

        ADUserInfo = ADUserName(sLogonUser, oConnection, oCommand, oRoot, oDomain, sADsPath)

    Case "supervisor"


End Select
```

End Function

Function ADUserGroups(sLogonUser, oConnection, oCommand, oRoot, oDomain, sADsPath)

```
Dim sFilter
Dim sAttribsToReturn
Dim sDepth
Dim sDomainSID
Dim vObjectSID
Dim sObjectSID
Dim sGroupRID
Dim iPrimaryGroupID
Dim oPrimaryGroup
Dim oRS

Dim value
Dim cGroups
Dim sDomain
Dim sLogonName

sDomain = Mid(sLogonUser, 1, Instr(1, sLogonUser, "\") - 1)
sLogonName = Mid(sLogonUser, Instr(1, sLogonUser, "\") + 1)

sFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & sLogonName & "))"
sAttribsToReturn = "memberOf,primaryGroupID,objectSID"
sDepth = "subTree"

ocommand.CommandText = sADsPath & ";" & sFilter & ";" & sAttribsToReturn & ";" & sDepth

Set oRS = ocommand.Execute

' Only one user should meet the criteria
If (oRS.RecordCount = 1) Then

    ' Get that user's info
    For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1

        If (oRS.Fields(i).Name = "memberOf") Then
            ' I've never seen this field come back with more than 
            ' ONE value, but the original code I started with 
            ' treated the memberOf property as though it was a 
            ' collection.  So, I've left it a collection until 
            ' I can verify it.  KLW

            cGroups = ""
            For Each value In oRS.Fields(i).Value
                cGroups = cGroups & replace(split(value,",")(0),"CN=","") & ";"
            Next

        ElseIf (oRS.Fields(i).Name = "primaryGroupID") Then
            ' need this to get the PrimaryGroup after other group membership has been obtained
            ' (Primary Group ID and Object SID ID needed to get the primary group)
            iPrimaryGroupID = oRS.Fields(i).Value

        ElseIf (oRS.Fields(i).Name = "objectSID") Then
            ' adVarBinary -- need this to get the PrimaryGroup.  
            ' It is not included in the memberOf group list

            vObjectSID = oRS.Fields(i).Value
            sObjectSID = SDDL_SID(vObjectSID)
        End If
    Next

    ' The primary group is not included in memberOf...

    ' We have the SDDL form of the user's SID.
    ' Remove the user's RID ( the last sub authority)
    ' up to the "-"
    '
    sDomainSID = Mid(sObjectSID, 1, (InStrREV(sObjectSID,"-")))

    ' Build the SID of the Primary group
    ' from the domainSID and the Primary Group RID in
    ' the PrimaryGroupID.
    '
    sGroupRID = StrRID(iPrimaryGroupID)
    sDomainSID = sDomainSID & sGroupRID

    ' Get the primary group   
    '
    set oPrimaryGroup = GetObject("LDAP://" & sDomain & "/<SID=" & sDomainSID & ">")

    cGroups = replace(split(oPrimaryGroup.Get("DistinguishedName"),",")(0),"CN=","") & ";" & cGroups

    ADUserGroups = cGroups

End If
```

End Function

Function ADUserName(sLogonUser, oConnection, oCommand, oRoot, oDomain, sADsPath)

```
Dim sFilter
Dim sAttribsToReturn
Dim sDepth
Dim sDomainSID
Dim vObjectSID
Dim sObjectSID
Dim sGroupRID
Dim iPrimaryGroupID
Dim oPrimaryGroup
Dim oRS

Dim value
Dim sDomain
Dim sLogonName

sDomain = Mid(sLogonUser, 1, Instr(1, sLogonUser, "\") - 1)
sLogonName = Mid(sLogonUser, Instr(1, sLogonUser, "\") + 1)


sFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" & sLogonName & "))"
sAttribsToReturn = "distinguishedName"
sDepth = "subTree"
ocommand.CommandText = sADsPath & ";" & sFilter & ";" & sAttribsToReturn & ";" & sDepth

Set oRS = ocommand.Execute

' Only one user should meet the criteria
If (oRS.RecordCount = 1) Then

    ' Get that user's info
    For i = 0 To oRS.Fields.Count - 1

        If (oRS.Fields(i).Name = "distinguishedName") Then
            ADUserName = replace(split(oRS.Fields(i).Value,",")(0),"CN=","")
        End If
    Next


End If
```

End Function

function SDDL_SID ( oSID )

```
dim IssueAuthorities(11)
Dim SubAuthorities
Dim strSDDL
Dim IssueIndex
Dim Revision
Dim i, j, k, index, p2, subtotal, dblSubAuth

IssueAuthorities(0) = "-0-0"
IssueAuthorities(1) = "-1-0"
IssueAuthorities(2) = "-2-0"
IssueAuthorities(3) = "-3-0"
IssueAuthorities(4) = "-4"
IssueAuthorities(5) = "-5"
IssueAuthorities(6) = "-?"
IssueAuthorities(7) = "-?"
IssueAuthorities(8) = "-?"
IssueAuthorities(9) = "-?"

' First byte is the revision value
'
Revision = ascb(midB(osid,1,1))

' Second byte is the number of sub authorities in the
' SID
'
SubAuthorities = CInt(ascb(midb(oSID,2,1)))
strSDDL = "S-" & Revision
IssueIndex = CInt(ascb(midb(oSID,8,1)))

strSDDL = strSDDL & IssueAuthorities(IssueIndex)

index = 9
i = index
for k = 1 to SubAuthorities 

    p2 = 0
    subtotal = 0
    for j = 1 to 4
        dblSubAuth = CDbl(ascb(midb(osid,i,1))) * (2^p2)
        subTotal = subTotal + dblSubAuth
        p2 = p2 + 8
        i = i + 1
    next

    ' Convert the value to a string, add it to the SDDL Sid and continue
    '
    strSDDL = strSDDL & "-" & cstr(subTotal)
next
SDDL_SID = strSDDL
```

end function

```
function Get_HexString( oSID )

Dim outStr, i, b
    outStr = ""
    for i = 0 to Ubound(oSid)
        b = hex(ascb(midb(oSid,i+1,1)))
        if( len(b) = 1 ) then b = "0" & b
        outStr = outStr & b
    next
    Get_HexString = outStr
end function

function StrRID( inVal )
    dim dLocal
    if( (inVal and &H80000000) <> 0 ) then
        dLocal = CDbl((inval and &H7FFFFFFF))
        dLocal = dLocal + 2^31
        StrRID = cstr(dLocal)
    else
        StrRID = Cstr(inVal)
    end if
end function
```